# ローカル環境で『rails s』でサーバが立ち上がらない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

『rails s』でローカルサーバが立ち上がるようにお力添えいただけると幸いです。

●環境
・mac os mojave 10.14.2
・ruby 2.3.1p112
・Rails 5.2.1
・rbenv 1.1.1
・Bundler version 1.17.2
・Homebrew 2.0.0

●bin/rails s 後のエラー

```
yoshidasachionoMacBook-Pro:profy yoshidayukio$ bin/rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.1 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:408:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': Error loading the 'mysql2' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? can't activate mysql2 (< 0.6.0, >= 0.4.4), already activated mysql2-0.3.18. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
~
~
~
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

●bin/bundle install 後の表示

```
Using rake 12.3.2
~
~
~
Bundle complete! 28 Gemfile dependencies, 107 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

●gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }
ruby '2.3.1'
gem 'rails', '5.2.1'
gem "mysql2", "0.3.18"
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
group :development, :test do
gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end
group :development do
gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
gem 'spring'
gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
group :test do
gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-material-design', '0.1.4'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'mini_magick'
group :production do
gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

●gemfileのmysqlを"0.4.4"へ修正後のエラー
    -bash: bin/install: No such file or directory

●bin/bundle installを実行後のエラー

````
yoshidasachionoMacBook-Pro:profy yoshidayukio$ bin/bundle install
--- ERROR REPORT TEMPLATE ---
# Error Report
## Questions
Please fill out answers to these questions, it'll help us figure out
why things are going wrong.
- **What did you do?**
  I ran the command `bin/bundle install`
- **What did you expect to happen?**
  I expected Bundler to...
- **What happened instead?**
  Instead, what happened was...
- **Have you tried any solutions posted on similar issues in our issue tracker, stack overflow, or google?**
  I tried...
- **Have you read our issues document, https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/doc/contributing/ISSUES.md?**
  ...
## Backtrace
```
Errno::EPERM: Failed to open TCP connection to index.rubygems.org:443 (Operation not permitted - connect(2) for "index.rubygems.org" port 443)
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:882:in `rescue in block in connect'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:858:in `start'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/vendor/net-http-persistent/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:702:in `start'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/vendor/net-http-persistent/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:967:in `reset'  /Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/vendor/net-http-persistent/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:630:in `connection_for'  /Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/vendored_persistent.rb:23:in `connection_for'  /Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/vendor/net-http-persistent/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:996:in `request'  /Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/fetcher/downloader.rb:56:in `request'  /Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/fetcher/downloader.rb:17:in `fetch'  /Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/fetcher/dependency.rb:10:in `available?'  /Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:158:in `use_api'  /Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:382:in `block in api_fetchers'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:382:in `select'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:382:in `api_fetchers'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:387:in `block in remote_specs'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/index.rb:11:in `build'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:386:in `remote_specs'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:89:in `specs'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:273:in `block (2 levels) in index'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:271:in `each'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:271:in `block in index'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/index.rb:11:in `build'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:268:in `index'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:258:in `resolve'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:158:in `resolve_remotely!'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/installer.rb:310:in `resolve_if_needed'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/installer.rb:84:in `block in run'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:12:in `block in lock'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in `open'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in `lock'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/installer.rb:73:in `run'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/installer.rb:25:in `install'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:65:in `run'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:235:in `block in install'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/settings.rb:143:in `temporary'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:234:in `install'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
/Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/bundle:3:in `load'
  bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
```
## Environment
```
Bundler       1.17.2
  Platforms   ruby, x86_64-darwin-17
Ruby          2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin17]
  Full Path   /Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby
  Config Dir  /Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/etc
RubyGems      2.5.1
  Gem Home    /Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  Gem Path    /Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0:/Users/yoshidayukio/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  User Path   /Users/yoshidayukio/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  Bin Dir     /Users/yoshidayukio/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin
OpenSSL       
  Compiled    OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
  Loaded      OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018
  Cert File   /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
  Cert Dir    /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
Tools         
  Git         2.19.1
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       rbenv 1.1.1
  chruby      not installed
```
## Bundler Build Metadata
```
Built At          2018-12-11
Git SHA           43e950846
Released Version  true
```
## Bundler settings
```
gemfile
  Set via BUNDLE_GEMFILE: "/Users/yoshidayukio/projects/profy/Gemfile"
```
## Gemfile
### Gemfile
```ruby
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }
ruby '2.3.1'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.2.1'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem "mysql2", "0.4.4"
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end
group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-material-design', '0.1.4'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'mini_magick'
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```
### Gemfile.lock
```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.1)
      activejob (= 5.2.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
    activerecord (5.2.1)
      activemodel (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      activerecord (= 5.2.1)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.6.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    archive-zip (0.11.0)
      io-like (~> 0.3.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (9.4.7)
      execjs
    bcrypt (3.1.12)
    bcrypt (3.1.12-java)
    bcrypt (3.1.12-x64-mingw32)
    bcrypt (3.1.12-x86-mingw32)
    bindex (0.5.0)
    bootsnap (1.3.2)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    bootsnap (1.3.2-java)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    bootstrap-material-design (0.1.4)
      bootstrap-sass (~> 3.0)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.7)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sass (>= 3.3.4)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (10.0.2)
    capybara (3.13.2)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.2)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (0.9.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    chromedriver-helper (2.1.0)
      archive-zip (~> 0.10)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    coderay (1.1.2)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    commonjs (0.2.7)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.4)
    crass (1.0.4)
    devise (4.6.0)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 6.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubi (1.8.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.10.0)
    ffi (1.10.0-java)
    ffi (1.10.0-x64-mingw32)
    ffi (1.10.0-x86-mingw32)
    font-awesome-rails (4.7.0.4)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 6.0)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.5.3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    io-like (0.3.0)
    jbuilder (2.8.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.3.3)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    kaminari (1.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
      kaminari-actionview (= 1.1.1)
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.1.1)
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-actionview (1.1.1)
      actionview
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-activerecord (1.1.1)
      activerecord
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-core (1.1.1)
    less (2.6.0)
      commonjs (~> 0.2.7)
    less-rails (2.8.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      less (~> 2.6.0)
      sprockets (> 2, < 4)
      tilt
    libv8 (3.16.14.19)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.2.3)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.2)
    mimemagic (0.3.3)
    mini_magick (4.9.2)
    mini_mime (1.0.1)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    msgpack (1.2.6)
    msgpack (1.2.6-java)
    msgpack (1.2.6-x64-mingw32)
    msgpack (1.2.6-x86-mingw32)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    mysql2 (0.3.18)
    mysql2 (0.3.18-x64-mingw32)
    mysql2 (0.3.18-x86-mingw32)
    mysql2 (0.3.18-x86-mswin32-60)
    nio4r (2.3.1)
    nio4r (2.3.1-java)
    nokogiri (1.10.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    nokogiri (1.10.1-java)
    nokogiri (1.10.1-x64-mingw32)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    nokogiri (1.10.1-x86-mingw32)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pry (0.12.2)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.9.0)
    pry (0.12.2-java)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.9.0)
      spoon (~> 0.0)
    pry-rails (0.3.9)
      pry (>= 0.10.4)
    public_suffix (3.0.3)
    puma (3.12.0)
    puma (3.12.0-java)
    rack (2.0.6)
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.1)
      actioncable (= 5.2.1)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.1)
      activejob (= 5.2.1)
      activemodel (= 5.2.1)
      activerecord (= 5.2.1)
      activestorage (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
      loofah (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    ref (2.0.0)
    regexp_parser (1.3.0)
    responders (2.4.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.2.0, < 6.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 6.0)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    rubyzip (1.2.2)
    sass (3.7.3)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    selenium-webdriver (3.141.0)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      rubyzip (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.2)
    spoon (0.0.6)
      ffi
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    therubyracer (0.12.3)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.15)
      ref
    thor (0.20.3)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    thread_safe (0.3.6-java)
    tilt (2.0.9)
    turbolinks (5.2.0)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    twitter-bootstrap-rails (4.0.0)
      actionpack (~> 5.0, >= 5.0.1)
      execjs (~> 2.7)
      less-rails (~> 2.8, >= 2.8.0)
      railties (~> 5.0, >= 5.0.1)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2018.9)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    uglifier (4.1.20)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    warden (1.2.8)
      rack (>= 2.0.6)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.0)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.0-java)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.3)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
  java
  ruby
  x64-mingw32
  x86-mingw32
  x86-mswin32
DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (>= 1.1.0)
  bootstrap-material-design (= 0.1.4)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 2.15)
  chromedriver-helper
  coffee-rails
  devise
  font-awesome-rails
  jbuilder
  jquery-rails
  kaminari
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  mini_magick
  mysql2 (= 0.3.18)
  pry-rails
  puma (~> 3.11)
  rails (= 5.2.1)
  rails_12factor
  sass-rails
  selenium-webdriver
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  therubyracer
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  twitter-bootstrap-rails
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.3.1p112
BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.2
```
--- TEMPLATE END ---
Unfortunately, an unexpected error occurred, and Bundler cannot continue.
First, try this link to see if there are any existing issue reports for this error:
https://github.com/bundler/bundler/search?q=Failed+to+open+TCP+connection+to+index.rubygems.org+443+%28Operation+not+permitted+-+connect%282%29+for+%22index.rubygems.org%22+port+443%29&type=Issues
If there aren't any reports for this error yet, please create copy and paste the report template above into a new issue. Don't forget to anonymize any private data! The new issue form is located at:
https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/new
````

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/173657

Answer (score 2):

mysql2 gem のバージョンが古いために、エラーが発生しているようです。

0.4.4 以上、 0.6.0 未満のバージョンを Gemfile にて指定することで解決すると思います。

具体的には、 1. Gemfile の mysql2 の記述を以下のように変えて

```
gem "mysql2", "0.4.4"
```

つぎに、  `bin/bundle install` する。

Comment: ありがとうございます。gemfileに指定するところまではわかるのですが、ネットで探していても該当記事が見つからず、コマンドをどのように入力するのかがわかりかねております。ご教授いただけると幸いです。

Comment: @YukioYoshida 追記しました。

Comment: 遅くなり失礼いたしました。gemfileを修正し、bin/installを実行したところ、質問に追記しましたが、エラーが起こりました。

Comment: @YukioYoshida bin/bundle install でした、回答を修正します

Comment: bin/bundle install後のエラーを追記いたしました。お手間おかけしますが、宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: @YukioYoshida これは、自分も見たことのないエラーですね。。ネットワークは繋がっていますか？

Comment: 確認いたしましたが、繋がっています。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/73766 上記エラーの解決策を見つけたのですが、ポートの指定などをしたことがありません。ご教授いただけると幸いです。